# YouTube autoplay query parameter is not working in OS

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to replace the contents of a iframe that's on my site via JavaScript. This works all well and good except for autoplay is not working in iOS.

```
<iframe id="gallery-video" class="yt-player" type="text/html" width="940" height="530" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cKJ1s7l3GrI?theme=light&rel=0&autohide=1&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1" frameloadVideoById border="0" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>

$('#gallery-video').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidID + '?autoplay=1');
```

Comment: It is working for me. Try this: `console.log('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidID + '?autoplay=1')`. Or maybe you are calling that piece of code before the element gets loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post the full code, it is really hard to tell the problem. One possible cause might be that `vidID` isn't defined in that scope, or you are calling that piece of code before the document has been fully loaded. Use `$(document).ready(function())` and try again.

You can always use Javascript's console and check for errors there. There is a useful language construct to store values in the console, you use it like this: `console.log(variable)`. Replace `variable` with the thing you are trying to replace: `console.log('https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidID + '?autoplay=1')`